# Why does Sidekiq and Rails return "wrong constant name Trash"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am trying to set up Sidekiq in my Rails app, but when I do:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

I get:

```
wrong constant name Trash?
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:30:in `const_defined?'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:30:in `block in qualified_const_defined?'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:29:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:29:in `inject'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:29:in `qualified_const_defined?'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:343:in `qualified_const_defined?'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:140:in `block in watch_namespaces'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:138:in `map'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:138:in `watch_namespaces'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:611:in `new_constants_in'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `load_file'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:323:in `require_or_load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.14.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:199:in `boot_system'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.14.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:42:in `parse'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.14.0/bin/sidekiq:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>
```

Redis is running and I have not made any workers.

I can start the Rails server.

Is it a bug?

Comment: and there is nothing in your app that has the name 'Trash'?

Comment: No. I have searched trough my application, the celluloid, rails and sidekiq and git repos. Didn't find `Trash` anywhere.

Comment: @andreas-lyngstad   how did you searched 'Trash' in your app ? I mean, as a string/sub-string in the content of each files of each directories ..., or as a file name itself, or as a directory name, or as a substring of both dir/file names?  Seems silly Q. but see my answer and you'll probably connect the dots :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have a mismatching file name, mapping class name the wrong way (maybe a typo).

Look for something like "nested controller" which contain a class declaration with a different name ... something like the following :

```
app/controllers/trash?/your_controller.rb

class Trash::YourController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
  end
end
```

see the mismatching/typo between `trash?` (dirname) and the relative class name `Trash`.

Comment: This is so long ago. I really don't remember the problem. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: never mind,  I just bump it down to keep track, It just happend to me too. I don't want to miss any more time the next one.